# Subversion commands work at the OS shell command-line but not within the IDE

Tags: svn, version-control, ide, subversion-edge, intersystems-cache-studio

I've organized my repository using TortoiseSVN. I was careful to use only svn commands while creating my file structure. Now all Subversion commands are working at the command line but not from within my IDE (Intersystems Cache Studio). Basically I'm trying to write a plug-in for my IDE to use Subversion from within the Studio. Trying to integrate Subversion into my IDE, something like Subversive, but for Cache Studio.  This occurred after reorganizing my code into directories. For example at the command-line, svn info and svn status and all other commands work perfectly. *All Subversion commands work at the command prompt!*

However, from within my IDE, svn info outputs this error:

**svn: warning: W155010: The node 'E:\elive2016\sourcecontrol\storage\XMLManager.xml' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist**

And svn status outputs the same errors:

**svn: warning: W155010: The node 'E:\elive2016\sourcecontrol\storage\XMLManager.xml' was not found.**
**svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist.**

No Subversion command except svnadmin create works from within the IDE. The same command(s) works perfectly well at the command prompt. I run Windows 10, InterSystems Cache Studio 2016 and Subversion 1.8.12. Any help, please?